# How can I loop through this array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop through this multidimensional array however it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
Array
(
    [*backingData] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => bob
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => bob
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => bob
                            [id] => 3
                        )
                 )
          )
 )
```

This is what I have right now:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                        for ($i=0;$i<=count($value);$i++) {

                            echo $value[$i]['id'];

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What's the output of your loop ?

Comment: I think you need another level of depth since $value is referring to one array with the key backingData

Comment: how do I add another level of depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way to do that :

```
function recursiveArrayLoop ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (is_array ($a)) {
            recursiveArrayLoop ($a);
        } else {
            var_dump ($a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your object data to array. use get_object_vars().

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
   foreach ($value as $key2=>$data) {
        $data = get_object_vars($data);
        echo $data['id'];
   }
}
```